# git commit shows leftover conflict marker on rst file contains ===

Tags: git, restructuredtext

I'm using standard git pre-commit, it use git diff --check.
I use the format rst file like

```
main subject
============

sub subject 1
-------------

sub subject 2
-------------
```

When I commit, it shows leftover conflict marker

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Switch to a different character for the top-level heading underline?

Comment: Maybe this will help, but I'm not sure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11394584/ See also https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6986.